# User account control window : There's no yes button , only no

Tags: windows-10, uac

I'm using Windows 10.

Accidentally the user with admin rights is deleted.

Now everytime i need to install something or do something else , the user account control window is showing , but there's no yes button , only No. so i can't do anything.

How to fix this ?
Thank you !

Comment: Check user account control setting, it may be set to high which will cause this.

Comment: @Moab No it;s not set to high. The problem that i've described begins after accidentally deleted the admin user. so no there;s only a normal user in system ( of course there;s the built in administrator but it's disabled and i cannot enable it because uac window is showing without yes button , only NO.

Answer (score 0):

**(A)** Add a user, restart in Safe Mode and see if you can add the user to the Admin group.

You can enable the normally disabled Administrator to do this.

Also try these steps:

```
Quick guide: Enable administrator account in Windows 10
Open “Run” with [Windows] + [R].
Type “cmd” and press [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Enter].
Type “net user administrator /active:yes”.
The administrator account is now activated.
To deactivate: “net user administrator /active:no”.
```

You need to login as Administrator when done

[Enable built in Admin Account](https://www.lifewire.com/enable-or-disable-administrator-account-in-windows-10-5095293)

```
Enable: Search for cmd in the taskbar search field > select Run as Administrator.
Type net user administrator /active:yes, and press enter. Wait for the confirmation and restart.
To disable, open the command prompt as an administrator and enter net user administrator /active:no
```

**===============**

**(B)**

**If all the above fails, then back up the machine and reinstall Windows fresh**.

Comment: How can i enable the built in Administrator , the User account control windows is showing and there's no yes button ? and also to add a user , the uac is showing again.

Comment: Did you read the entire article I posted?

Comment: I added another set of steps near the beginning of my answer - try those steps.

Comment: Yes , but i can;t add a user , i can't enable the built in Administrator and i can't open command prompt with Run as Administrator.. On all of these actions the UAC window is showing and there;s no yes button to confirm.

Comment: It appears you will need to back up the machine and reinstall Windows